# Mockito - Mocking a method with parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am writing unit tests for a method that takes in argument `id` which is something like below :

```
 public void searchid(String id) {
    Document doc = Repository.findDocument(id); //returns a document
    if (doc == null) {
      System.out.println("id missing");
    } else {
      String stringRecord = doc.asJsonString(); //converting doc to string
```

Here `Repository.findDocument(id)` is returning a document.
In my unit test, I am getting the JSON file from `src/test/resources`. So, how do I mock `Repository.findDocument(id)`, so as to fetch the file from my resource instead ?

Thanks,

Comment: Is `Repository.findDocument()` a `static` method?

Comment: A similiar question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito.

Comment: No. I am autowiring and then using `findDocument`

Comment: Do you use `@Autowire Repository repository` in your unit test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to testability is that you have a **field** `repository` that gets constructor-injected into your class. This way you can easily substitute the real  repository by a fake instance (e.g a mockito mock).

The best source for learning how to write testable code, that I know, is http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/

**UPDATED at 2023-09-18**
Unfortunately the above link is broken. But I found most of the material referenced here:

- https://testing.googleblog.com/2008/08/by-miko-hevery-so-you-decided-to.html
- https://testing.googleblog.com/2008/07/how-to-write-3v1l-untestable-code.html

Interested readers will skim https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Atesting.googleblog.com%20misko%20hevery

Comment: the link is not working anymore

Answer (score 2):

You can try to mock the `Repository.findDocument(id)` call in your unit test method.

```
Mockito.when(Repository.findDocument(Mockito.isA(String.class))).thenReturn(Mockito.mock(Document.class));
```

This will return Mocked Document object whenever the `Repository.findDocument(id)` call is made.

Comment: So, I should parse the JSON file and store the ID and pass it in the above function ryt ?

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that you need Document object, I have edited my answer. If you wish to mock Document object with custom data you could do it.

Comment: And where should I call my method `searchid(id)` ?

Comment: Both the mocking code and `searchid(id)` should be in your unit test method

Comment: Hey, how can I mock Document object with custom data ? Sorry to ask but I am a newbie to this.